# Method output depending on previous code outside scope?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
    public static void method1(int v, int t) {
        float sum = 0;

        for (int j = 1; j <= t; j++) {
            GG g = new GG();
            MS ms = new MS();
            Graph graph = g.generate1(v);
            total_sum += ms.run(graph, v);
        }
        System.out.println("N = " + Integer.toString(v) +" sum: " + Float.toString(sum / (float) t));
    }

    public static void method2(int v, int t) {
        float sum = 0;

        for (int j = 1; j <= t; j++) {
            GG g = new GG();
            MS ms = new MS();
            Graph graph = g.generate2(v);
            sum += ms.run(graph, v);
        }
        System.out.println("N = " + Integer.toString(v) +" sum: " + Float.toString(sum / (float) t));
    }

    public static void main() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 18; i++) {

            int  n          = 1 << i;
            method1(n, 5);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 18; i++) {
            int  n          = 1 << i;
            method2(n, 5);
        }
```

If I include the first for loop (the one that includes `method1`) n the `main`, I get a different answer for `method2` than if I omitted the first for loop. Does anyone know why this might be? How can the results of the first for loop affect the second for loop if both are in different scope? I instantiate new objects in each method so I'm not sure why this would be the case.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve] of the issue. This code refers to classes and methods that are not defined here, so nobody other than you can determine what it actually does. Don't just include the missing code; distill it down to a *minimal* amount of code which exhibits the issue you're asking about.

Comment: If `GG` or `MS` have static members then even new instances may observe side effects.

Comment: @Marvin Thank you. This is specifically for static variables right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `static` means simplified: Shared across multiple instances. For variables that can mean that every instance of a class accesses the same value and that modifications done by one instance are visible in all other instances as well.